# how can i make a component independent of regular deployment?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, bit, code-splitting

I have a react app

name: **example**

inside that i have

```
component-a
component-b
component-c
```

How can i make independent deployment for **component-c** without deploying the whole app (i.e **example** here) ?

**thought i tried:**

- component-c i can put on npm but that again required update of package in **main app** once i release a new version of **component-c**. resulting in a new deployment of the whole app.
- Hosting on something like **bit.dev**.

Not sure what is the right way to do this.

Comment: webpack and diffrent builds

Comment: Isn't that requireds build and publishing the whole app again ? @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze ?

Comment: Not necessarily, Finally we I am going with module federations and nx. That is somewhat resolving my use case. Thanks for all the response.